# yet another clearInterval in javascript not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

Belive me i ve seen many solutions i still dont know why this doesnt work.

```
timerId = 0;
    $("#dumpStartId").click(function(){
        var proId = $("#curProfileId").val();
        timerId = setInterval(function(){
        showact();
        showactdat();
        },1000);
    });
    $("#dumpStopId").click(function(){
        clearInterval(timerId); 
        document.getElementById('curSeqId').value = "";
        if(timerId)
        {
            clearInterval(timerId);
        }           
    });
```

dumpstartid and dumpstopid are the ids of the two buttons. Even after clicking stop the intervals are executing continuosly. Im not sure whats wrong with this code. No errors in the console too.

Update: I can observer that sometimes after insanely pressing the button for around 5 or 6 times it comes to a complete halt. Cant this thing stop instantaneously (or is too much to ask??)

Comment: Seems to be working fine in chrome? http://jsfiddle.net/H3Dyq/

Comment: @WSkid yes it is, the function which is called int the setinterval is an ajax function that links to a php file which recieves a stream of xml data and decodes it all and return a value and this process repeats itself. In my local also it stops but not instantaneously so is there a way to stop it instantaneously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because the function the setInterval is calling was problematic which polls a rest service at a varied interval from the setIntervals interval causing it to conflict. I ve corrected it and that fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

setInterval iterates every "Millisecond-Value" you've given till it reaches the clearInterval. Try using onmousedown instead of onclick.